# jQuery UI: Container div resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In the following example there are two draggable divs in a container div. When the second draggable div is removed (by clicking on the button) the first div moves up and the container is resized ([see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/dzSRR/10/)). The first div should not move when the second div is removed, as its position is absolute. What's wrong with this code?

The HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="background-color:blue;width:100%;height:100%"></div>
<button onclick="removeDiv()">Remove</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $div0 = $('<div id="div0" />').appendTo('#container');
    $div0.draggable();
    $div0.offset({ top: 200, left: 350});
    $div0.css('background-color','white');
    $div0.css('width','150px');
    $div0.css('height','200px');
    $div0.text(0);

    var $div1 = $('<div id="div1" />').appendTo('#container');
    $div1.draggable();
    $div1.offset({ top: 200, left: 50});
    $div1.css('background-color','white');
    $div1.css('width','150px');
    $div1.css('height','200px');
    $div1.text(1);

 });


function removeDiv () {
    $('#div0').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both draggable divs have relative positions. You can fix them up like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dzSRR/13/

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#container > div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Because they're now absolutely-positioned, you'll need to give the parent div a height. If you use `100%`, you also need to apply that height to `html, body`.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dzSRR/14/